# Load or import map for use by class instance in matlab

Tags: matlab, class, import, load, instance

I have a `containers.Map` file/variable that I've defined through the Matlab Command Window (or some other script) and have saved it to directory. I'd like to be able to have an instance of my class be able to use that map without having to define it in the class definition, or with some other function that defines it each time the function is called. So I have:

```
myMap.mat
```

and in a separate `myClass.m` file (in the same directory) i'd like to be able to call myMap like so:

```
classdef myClass < handle
    properties
        number
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass(input)
            obj.number = myMap(input);
        end
    end
end
```

What's the most efficient way to get myMap "into the class" so that the instance can use it? `matfile` has been giving me some Warnings about format not supporting partial loading, and I can't imagine `load` is terribly efficient. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches you can use but, honestly, I think the simplest one would be using a [persistent](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) object in your class constructor, as follows:

```
classdef myClass < handle
    properties
        number
    end

    methods
        function obj = myClass(input)
            persistent pmap;

            if (isempty(pmap))
                load('map.mat','map');
                pmap = map;
            end

            obj.number = pmap(input);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Tommaso. To clarify, this would still load the map each time an instance of the class was created correct? Or does it apply to all instances?

Comment: This loads the map only when the first instance is created. It's a lazy initialization. When the second instance is created, `pmap` has already been instantiated and what is inside the `if` statement will be skipped.